# Laravel 8 Multiple Table Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

This is a long post, sorry in advance.

I have a couple of questions regarding the diagram below.

[image: table relationship]

1. How do I create a relationship for these tables? (tried "belongsToMany" and "hasMany")
2. Should I use Eloquent or Query Builder to get desired result? (image is attached below for desired result)
3. Is "*client_order_items*" a pivot table?
4. How can you distinguish a pivot table? Is it because the table has multiple
   foreign keys?
5. How can I access "*images*" table from "**Manufacturer**" model? Can "hasOneThrough / hasManyThrough" achieve this?
6. Is the desired result achievable purely using Eloquent or DB Query?

```php
//sample:
Manufacturers::find(2)->client_order_items->cars->images->car_image
```

I tried considering "*client_order_items*" as a pivot table then making relationships using "belongsToMany" in "**Manufacturer**", "**Car**" and "**ClientOrder**" models.

```php
// App\Model\Manufacturer.php
public function client_orders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ClientOrder::class, 
           "client_order_items", "manufacturer_id", "client_order_id")
           ->withPivot('id', 'quantity', 'car_id');;
}
public function cars() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class, 
           "client_order_items", "manufacturer_id", "car_id");
}

// App\Model\Car.php
public function client_orders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ClientOrder::class, 
           "client_order_items", "car_id", "client_order_id");
}
public function manufacturers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Manufacturer::class, 
           "client_order_items", "car_id", "manufacturer_id");
}

// App\Model\ClientOrder.php
public function cars() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Manufacturer::class, 
           "client_order_items", "client_order_id", "car_id");
}
public function manufacturers() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Manufacturer::class, 
           "client_order_items", "client_order_id", "manufacturer_id");
}
```

I also tried "hasMany" relationship:

```php
// App\Model\Manufacturer.php
public function client_order_items() {
    return $this->hasMany(ClientOrderItems::class);
}
```

```php
// App\Model\Cars.php
public function client_order_items() {
    return $this->hasMany(ClientOrderItems::class);
}
```

```php
// App\Model\ClientOrder.php
public function client_order_items() {
    return $this->hasMany(ClientOrderItems::class);
}
```

```php
// App\Model\ClientOrderItems.php
public function car() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
}
public function manufacturer() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Manufacturer::class);
}
public function client_order() {
    return $this->belongsTo(ClientOrder::class);
}
```

My goal is to get the result if i did something like this:

```json
// Manufacturer::find(2)->client_orders

// Desired Result:
[
    {
        "client_order_id": 88062,
        "first_name": "Clark",
        "last_name": "Kent",
        "order_items": [
            {
                "client_order_item_id": 37394,
                "quantity": 1,
                "car_id": 68,
                "image": "path_img1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "client_order_id": 60978,
        "first_name": "Bruce",
        "last_name": "Wayne",
        "order_items": [
            {
                "client_order_item_id": 79913,
                "quantity": 1,
                "car_id": 68,
                "image": "path_img1"
            },
            {
                "client_order_item_id": 84743,
                "quantity": 1,
                "car_id": 95,
                "image": "path_img2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But the result I'm currently getting (with "belongsToMany") is:

```json
// Manufacturer::find(2)->client_orders

// Current Result:
[
    {
        "id": 88062,
        "first_name": "Clark",
        "last_name": "Kent",
        "pivot": {
            "manufacturer_id": 2,
            "client_order_id": 88062,
            "id": 37394,
            "quantity": 1,
            "car_id": 68
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 60978,
        "first_name": "Bruce",
        "last_name": "Wayne",
        "pivot": {
            "manufacturer_id": 2,
            "client_order_id": 60978,
            "id": 79913,
            "quantity": 1,
            "car_id": 68
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 60978,
        "first_name": "Bruce",
        "last_name": "Wayne",
        "pivot": {
            "manufacturer_id": 2,
            "client_order_id": 60978,
            "id": 84743,
            "quantity": 1,
            "car_id": 95
        }
    }
]
```

Sorry again for the long post.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting and reading for couple of hours, I was able to get the result I want.

**Making the relationships:**

Manufacturer model has "belongsToMany" relationship with "ClientOrder"

```php
// App\Model\Manufacturer
public function client_orders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ClientOrder::class, 'client_order_items', 'manufacturer_id', 'client_order_id');
}
```

"Car" and "Image" model has "hasMany" relationship. This will give us access to "Image" model from "ClientOrderItems" model.

```php
// App\Models\Car
public function image() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Image::class);
} 
 
// App\Models\Image
public function cars() {
    return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
}
```

**Creating Accessors to Models**

In "ClientOrder" model, create an accessor for the "order_items" key. This will fetch rows from "OrderLineItems" that are related to the "manufacturer_id" and "client_order_id".

```php
// App\Models\ClientOrder
protected $appends = ["order_items"];

public function getOrderItemsAttribute() {
    $items = ClientOrderItems::where("manufacturer_id", '=', $this->pivot->manufacturer_id)
        ->where("client_order_id","=",$this->pivot->client_order_id)
        ->select(["id as client_order_item_id","car_id","quantity"])
        ->get();
    return $items;
}
```

In "ClientOrderItems" pivot model, create an accessor for the "image".

```php
// App\Models\ClientOrderItems
protected $appends = ["image"];

public function getImageAttribute() {
    return Car::find($this->car_id)->image->car_image;
}
```

The result of the 2 codes above looks something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "client_order_item_id": 79913,
        "quantity": 1,
        "car_id": 68,
        "image": "path_img1"
     },
     {
        "client_order_item_id": 84743,
        "quantity": 1,
        "car_id": 95,
        "image": "path_img2"
     }
]
```

More on Accessors & Mutators:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

**Retrieving Records**

To get the "client orders" that are related to manufacturer_id, use:

```php
/// App\Http\Controllers\ManufacturerController;
public function index() {
    $client_order = Manufacturer::find($manufacturer_id)->client_orders->unique("id")->values();
}
```

Above code will only fetch unique rows from "client_orders" table. Appending the related "order_items" for each row with the help of accessors.

```json
[
    {
        "client_order_id": 88062,
        "first_name": "Clark",
        "last_name": "Kent",
        "order_items": [
            {
                "client_order_item_id": 37394,
                "quantity": 1,
                "car_id": 68,
                "image": "path_img1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "client_order_id": 60978,
        "first_name": "Bruce",
        "last_name": "Wayne",
        "order_items": [
            {
                "client_order_item_id": 79913,
                "quantity": 1,
                "car_id": 68,
                "image": "path_img1"
            },
            {
                "client_order_item_id": 84743,
                "quantity": 1,
                "car_id": 95,
                "image": "path_img2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```